# Visa requirement for Indian living in the UK for travel to Serbia and Bulgaria

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, bulgaria, serbia, uk-residents

I am an Indian citizen living and working in the UK for 5 years now. I hold a Tier-2 resident permit in the UK with an Indian passport.

I am keen on visiting Sofia, Bulgaria en-route to Belgrade, Serbia in August 2015. As I hold a visa issued by the UK (which is part of the EU), and I am a resident here, do I still need a Schengen Visa to visit Sofia, Bulgaria and then to Belgrade, Serbia?

It's mentioned on their embassy websites, that if a member EU nation visa is there, I don't need a Schengen for these countries?

It would be really helpful, if someone can provide the answer to my questions soon please.

Comment: Yes i think you need visa to visit these countries. Only with UK passport you can go there without visa.

Comment: You don't need a Schengen visa to visit these countries and they can't issue one (although if you have one from a visit to a Schengen country, it might allow you to enter Bulgaria or Serbia too) but you might need a local visa instead.

Answer (score 5):

As @Relaxed indicated, Bulgaria and Serbia aren't part of the Schengen area (yet). They will [both](http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime) let [you in](http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html) if you have a Schengen visa, but it's not required.

You do need a local visa for Bulgaria, it seems it doesn't care about your status in the UK, but Serbia will let you in.

*Bulgaria ([reference](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/Consular/050615_EN_VisaRegime_for_foreigners_ordinary_passports.pdf))*

> *Last update: 03.06.2015*
>
> ```
> Country Visa is required
>
> India    Yes
> ```
>
> On 25 January 2012 the Council of Ministers of the Republic of
> Bulgaria adopted a decision according to which by the date of
> Bulgaria’s accession to the Schengen area, our country will
> unilaterally apply a visa-free system for holders of valid Schengen
> visas. They will have the right to enter and reside in the Republic of
> Bulgaria for a period of no more than three months in any six-month
> period from the date of the first entry, without needing to have a
> Bulgarian short-stay visa. The decision entered into force on
> 31.01.2012.

*Serbia*

> At its meeting of 30 October 2014, the Government of the Republic of
> Serbia adopted the Decision on visa free entry to the Republic of
> Serbia for holders of foreign passports having a valid Schengen, **UK**
> and other Member States' visa, or visa of the United States of
> America, and for holders of foreign passports having residence permit
> in the countries of the Schengen area, EU or the United States of
> America, which was published in the "Official Gazette of RS", No. 119
> of 31 October 2014 and which will enter into force on 8 November 2014